# How to skip validation for DRF serializer FloatField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

#### Problem

I need to add the ability to save the `minimum_commission` as positive number, but None is also available. I have added the serialiser:

```
class Appartement(models.Model):
    minimum_commission = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)

class RentalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    minimum_commission = serializers.FloatField(required=False, min_value=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartement
        fields = (
            'minimum_commission',
        )
```

But when I pass the empty string from the form(or shell), I see the `A valid number is required` validation error.

```
In [21]: ser = RentalTestSerializer(data={'minimum_commission': ''})

In [22]: ser.is_valid()
Out[22]: False

In [23]: ser.errors
Out[23]:
ReturnDict([('minimum_commission',
             [ErrorDetail(string=u'A valid number is required.', code=u'invalid')])])
```

#### Possible solution

At first I have added custom field: `BlankableFloatField` which convert empty string to the None:

```
class BlankableFloatField(serializers.FloatField):
    """
    We wanted to be able to receive an empty string ('') or 'null' for a float field
    and in that case turn it into a None number
    """
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data in ['', 'null']:
            return None

        return super(BlankableFloatField, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

and added the custom validation:

```
class RentalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    minimum_commission = BlankableFloatField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartement
        fields = (
            'minimum_commission',
        )

    def validate_minimum_commission(self, value):
        if value and value < 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("Minimum commission should be greater than 0"))
        return value
```

For now it works as expected:

```
In [38]: ser = RentalTestSerializer(data={'minimum_commission': ''})

In [39]: ser.is_valid()
Out[39]: True
```

but I think is there way to do it more elegant?

---

#### UPD:

as I see the main issue is into passing the empty string from the form. I need it to reset the `minimum_commission` column. So, the final solution is:

```
class Appartement(models.Model):
    # I have added the blank=True and validator
    minimum_commission = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)]) 

class RentalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # I continue to use the custom field to transform empty space to the None 
    # but instead of custom validation just added the allow_null=True and min_value validator.
    minimum_commission = BlankableFloatField(required=False, allow_null=True, min_value=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartement
        fields = (
            'minimum_commission',
        )
```

---

#### UPD2:

After plaing with the solution of processing empty string I found that clearer is to skip sending empty string on front-end at all and set the `default=None` into serialiser. Also, the custom field is not needed anymore.

```
class Appartement(models.Model):
    minimum_commission = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None) 

class RentalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    minimum_commission = serializer.FloatField(required=False, allow_null=True, min_value=0, default=None)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartement
        fields = (
            'minimum_commission',
        )
```

Comment: Can you include the model of Appartement ? it is important to see if you can stored null for the field

Comment: In the model it is defined with `minimum_commission = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)`

Answer (score 2):

Like I mentioned in the comment - the appartement model would be useful.

But if I understand correctly, what you want to achieve should be quite simple as follows:

```
class Appartement(models.Model):
    minimum_commission = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class RentalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Appartement
        fields = (
            'minimum_commission',
        )
```

With this implementation, `minimum_commission` is optional, and it accepts null values too.

Comment: Thanks, @enthusiast-martin. This works in the shell, when I pass the None, -10, 10. I have just added the min validator to the model: `minimum_commission = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])`. But the issue is still with processing empty string, which is passed if no value on the form.I see the `A valid number is required.`.

Comment: @IvanRostovsky empty string is a string, so it would be rejected. If you really need to accept empty strings, you need to handle it  - good option is the custom field like you have in your post.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I start to avoid handling empty string and just added condition on front-end to send nothing if value is empty. Also in serialzer I have added the `default=None` to support reseting column. Thanks for the help, @enthusiast-martin!

Comment: @IvanRostovsky yes, good. that's better. was not sure if you had access to the other side.happy to help.